# Using AdWords BatchJob in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get new BatchJob (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/batch-jobs) up and running, however missing one part.

Docs says:

> The good news is that your client library of choice will have a
>   utility that handles constructing and sending the request for you. The
>   example below uses the **BatchJobHelper** utility from the Java client
>   library.

However PHP library is missing that Helper and any method that should do that...

Anyone had any luck sending request to API using BatchJob? I can't find any working example anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the branch experimental they are rewriting the API. It seems that the BatchJobHelper is missing still (current day of write this), [see my issue in github requesting it](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues/145).

For get BatchJobs you should use the BatchJobService class, which is instantiated from the adword service. This is a example snippet:

```
$batch_job_service = $adWordsServices->get($session, 'BatchJobService', 'v201605', 'cm');

try
{
    /** @var BatchJobReturnValue $result */
    $result = $batch_job_service->mutate($operations);
}
catch(ApiException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

if(!empty($result) && $result instanceof Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201605\cm\BatchJobReturnValue)
{
    $batch_job = reset($result->getValue());
}
else 
{
    echo 'Result is empty or no valid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using composer to load the new v201603 version of adwords you will need to also adjust your composer file to map the utils since they are duplicated across the other versions for some reason.. Not sure why they did this. you should be able to find the class you need with the following path. Hope this helps.

```
{
"require": {
    "googleads/googleads-php-lib": "8.3.0"
 },
 "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
         "vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/v201601"
            ]
  }
}
```